# I was getting error while working with npm modules, when I type any cmd related to npm it gives the following error

Tags: node.js, npm, module, node-modules, npm-package

When I type 'npm -v' I got the following error says
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1080
throw error;
Error:cannot find module 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js'
I could'nt even find the above specified path 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js',

rather i have only this path C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js
where my npm-cli.js was located.

Could anyone find the solution for this problem?